# How does MATLAB's fit() function differentiate arbitrary MATLAB expressions for Levenberg-Marquardt to be applicable?

Tags: matlab, optimization, gradient, curve-fitting, derivative

As far as I understand the LM algorithm, it is an improvement over the Newton's method, so very roughly speaking, an algorithm which tries to build a path in the parameter space, leading to the point where the error function is minimal, which follows the direction of the biggest gradient of error function (differentiated with respect to the parameters).

I have written a Newton's method optimizer for a neural network once, as an exercise, and the critical part of the algorithm was that we could apply the chain rule (error backpropagation) to compute the gradient. And it was me who used the chain rule to the write out a formula for the gradients. (Essentially by symbolic differentiating on paper once and coding the resulting formula.)

In MATLAB (Curve Fitting Toolbox), there is a standard `fit()` function, which claims to use Levenberg-Marquardt's method to fit basically any parametric MATLAB expression as well as a set of prepared models.

Well, I suspect that the prepared models could be pre-differentiated by Mathworks' engineers to generate the code for the gradients. But what about the 'arbitrary' fits?

Is MATLAB trying to do symbolic differentiation implicitly? I highly doubt that anyone can write rules for differentiation of all the complex MATLAB constructions, i.e. classes and enumerations.

Or, maybe MATLAB is just differentiating the function by evaluating it in ξ and ξ+Δξ and dividing by Δξ? But that would require finding the best shift and require `n+1` function evaluations, where `n` is the number of parameters optimized.

And in any case, even this strategy would fail if the function is not differentiable, which I suspect to be the case for almost any general MATLAB expression.

Could anyone give a plausible hypothesis of what is actually happening inside?
(Well, knowing what **actually** happens inside would be even better, but even an informal insight would be great.)